# resin memory issue

Tags: memory-management, jvm, resin

I started the resin 3.0.28 using the jvm parameter :

```
    -Xms6300M -Xmx6300M -Xss128k -XX:ThreadStackSize=256 -XX:MaxPermSize=128M 
-XX:PermSize=128M -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+UseParallelGC 
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
```

but the memory retained has been over 10GB

What's wrong with the resin?
I use jmap -heap and the output is as below:
it shows that jvm heap memory is in normal state.

```
Attaching to process ID 9456, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 10.0-b22

using thread-local object allocation.
Parallel GC with 16 thread(s)

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70
   MaxHeapSize      = 6606028800 (6300.0MB)
   NewSize          = 2686976 (2.5625MB)
   MaxNewSize       = -65536 (-0.0625MB)
   OldSize          = 5439488 (5.1875MB)
   NewRatio         = 2
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   PermSize         = 134217728 (128.0MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 134217728 (128.0MB)

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 2155151360 (2055.3125MB)
   used     = 1966086568 (1875.0062637329102MB)
   free     = 189064792 (180.30623626708984MB)
   91.22730795112228% used
From Space:
   capacity = 23265280 (22.1875MB)
   used     = 13849352 (13.207771301269531MB)
   free     = 9415928 (8.979728698730469MB)
   59.527983329665496% used
To Space:
   capacity = 23068672 (22.0MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 23068672 (22.0MB)
   0.0% used
PS Old Generation
   capacity = 4404019200 (4200.0MB)
   used     = 3854164456 (3675.6176528930664MB)
   free     = 549854744 (524.3823471069336MB)
   87.51470602126349% used
PS Perm Generation
   capacity = 134217728 (128.0MB)
   used     = 53393152 (50.919677734375MB)
   free     = 80824576 (77.080322265625MB)
   39.78099822998047% used
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean my "memory retained"? I will assume that you mean the memory allocated by the process itself:

The heap won't use more than you specify (apart from some fragmentation, but that's minor).  "Other objects" in the process use this space, Although there could be something wrong with resin or the JVM, especially if the memory is ever increasing steadily over weeks, the amount of memory used by resin and the hvm could also be normal.

Have a look at my attempt to answer another similar question:

[JVM memory consumption double of heapsize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928837/jvm-memory-consumption-double-of-heapsize/6723476)

In short: Make sure your looking at the correct process size. I typically se 1-1.5 GB of non java-heap space for resin on a 32-bit Debian system (which of course make your 4 GB sound a lot).

Furthermore:
-Xss128k -XX:ThreadStackSize=256

will be interpreted as

-XX:ThreadStackSize=128 -XX:ThreadStackSize=256,

so you might want to remove one of them... (see http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-dev/2011-June/004272.html)